# How do I add CSS styling to my div on Grid dynamically in umbraco 7.13?

Tags: c#, .net, web, umbraco

I want to add **dynamic CSS class** to my custom Grid row configuration in **Umbraco 7.13**.
I want to add styling and setting dinamically when any new div was added to the grid in **Umbraco**.

I need help for this.

see atttached screenshot
i've tried this
1. i've added one content page of document type is "Content Page" 2. after that i've change row configuration to content page base from datatype and add as much possible row configuration 3. now i need to add css class to each row configuration 4. so when any non technical person will add some content to any row then given css was automatically applied is there any way to do like this...if yes then please help me out... Thanks in advance

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TMD7.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome! Could you please add some code snippets of what you've already tried ?

Comment: Try to add things that you have done so far.

Comment: 1. i've added one content page of document type is "Content Page" 
2. after that i've change row configuration to content page base from datatype and add as much possible row configuration 
3. now i need to add css class to each row configuration 
4. so when any non technical person will add some content to any row then given css was automatically applied

is there any way to do like this...if yes then please help me out...
Thanks in advance